# How can I store captures from a Perl regular expression into separate variables?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, regex-group

I have a regex:

```
/abc(def)ghi(jkl)mno(pqr)/igs
```

How would I capture the results of each parentheses into 3 different variables, one for each parentheses? Right now I using one array to capture all the results, they come out sequential but then I have to parse them and the list could be huge.

```
@results = ($string =~ /abc(def)ghi(jkl)mno(pqr)/igs);
```

Comment: Do you want to count how many times the pattern is matched? That's what it seems like to me...

Comment: i need to process the matches

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous to me, but I think you want to do something like this:

```
my (@first, @second, @third);
while( my ($first, $second, $third) = $string =~ /abc(def)ghi(jkl)mno(pqr)/igs) {
    push @first, $first;
    push @second, $second;
    push @third, $third;
}
```

Comment: that's a bit long winded. when captured, you can use back references

Comment: ghostdog74: that's a matter of taste. If you really name your variables $first and $second then you might as well use $1 and $2 indeed, but if you give them more descriptive names then it can improve readability to do it like this.

Comment: -1. I have to agree with ghostdog74; capturing to the  $1 .. series of variables is just cleaner in modern Perl.  While you *can* do it, doesn't mean it's probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @leon ,true, but since he is going to put them in arrays anyway, what you really care is the array name. who doesn't know what $1, $2 .. is?

Comment: This answer is unfortunately incorrect. The `while` loop in this answer will loop infinitely if `$string` matches (due to the list context inside the `while` expression).

Answer (score 10):

Starting with 5.10, you can use [named capture buffers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %data;

my $s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqr';

if ($s =~ /abc (?<first>def) ghi (?<second>jkl) mno (?<third>pqr)/x ) {
    push @{ $data{$_} }, $+{$_} for keys %+;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%data;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'first' => [
                       'def'
                     ],
          'second' => [
                        'jkl'
                      ],
          'third' => [
                       'pqr'
                     ]
        };
```

For earlier versions, you can use the following which avoids having to add a line for each captured buffer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqr';

my @arrays = \ my(@first, @second, @third);

if (my @captured = $s =~ /abc (def) ghi (jkl) mno (pqr) /x ) {
    push @{ $arrays[$_] }, $captured[$_] for 0 .. $#arrays;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @arrays;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'def'
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          'jkl'
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          'pqr'
        ];
```

But I like keeping related data in a single data structure, so it is best to go back to using a hash. This does require an auxiliary array, however:

```
my %data;
my @keys = qw( first second third );

if (my @captured = $s =~ /abc (def) ghi (jkl) mno (pqr) /x ) {
    push @{ $data{$keys[$_]} }, $captured[$_] for 0 .. $#keys;
}
```

Or, if the names of the variables really are `first`, `second` etc, or if the names of the buffers don't matter but only order does, you can use:

```
my @data;
if ( my @captured = $s =~ /abc (def) ghi (jkl) mno (pqr) /x ) {
    push @{ $data[$_] }, $captured[$_] for 0 .. $#captured;
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to do a deep copy in that first example? I'd just pull out Storable's dclone. Either that, or your example needs some looping to build up that values you store in `$data`. :)

Comment: @brian I was thinking of parsing a file where each line gives you a `first` and a `second` and a `third` value and storing those values in their own arrays. Compare with Leon Timmerman's example ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259784/how-can-i-store-captures-from-a-perl-regular-expression-into-separate-variables/2259795#2259795 )

Answer (score 3):

An alternate way of doing it would look like ghostdog74's answer, but using an array that stores hash references:

```
my @results;
while( $string =~ /abc(def)ghi(jkl)mno(pqr)/igs) {
    my ($key1, $key2, $key3) = ($1, $2, $3);
    push @results, { 
        key1 => $key1,
        key2 => $key2,
        key3 => $key3,
    };
}

# do something with it

foreach my $result (@results) {
    print "$result->{key1}, $result->{key2}, $result->{key3}\n";
}
```

with the main advantage here of using a single data structure, AND having a nice readable loop.

Answer (score 2):

@OP, when parenthesis are captured, you can use the variables $1,$2....these are backreferences

```
$string="zzzabcdefghijklmnopqrsssszzzabcdefghijklmnopqrssss";
while ($string =~ /abc(def)ghi(jkl)mno(pqr)/isg) {
    print "$1 $2 $3\n";
}
```

output

```
$ perl perl.pl
def jkl pqr
def jkl pqr
```

Comment: Note his use of the g modifier. He's doing a global match, so I assume he wants to store multiple matches.

Comment: Also, $1 and so on are not "backreferences", they are captures.  Parentheses and backreferences are *related*, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could have three different regex's each focusing on specific groups. Obviously, you would like to just assign different groups to different arrays in the regex, but I think your only option is to split the regex up.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regex containing named capture groups. You do this with the `?<myvar>` construct at the beginning of the capture group:

```
/(?<myvar>[0-9]+)/
```

You may then refer to those named capture groups using a `$+{myvar}` form.

Here is a contrived example:

```
perl -ne '/^systemd-(?<myvar>[^:]+)/ && { print $+{myvar} . "\n"}' /etc/passwd
```

Given a typical password file, it pulls out the systemd users and returns the names less the systemd prefix. It uses a capture group named `myvar`. This is just an example thrown together to illustrate the use of capture group variables.