# How to Regex Multiple URLs From Same Variable In Perl

Tags: regex, perl, url

I'm trying to search a field in a database to extract URLs.  Sometimes there will be more than 1 URL in a field and I would like to extract those in to separate variables (or an array).

I know my regex isn't going to cover all possibilities.  As long as I flag on anything that starts with http and ends with a space I'm ok.

The problem I'm having is that my efforts either seem to get only 1 URL per record or they get only 1 the last letter from each URL.  I've tried a couple different techniques based on solutions other have posted but I haven't found a solution that works for me.

Sample input line:
Testing http://marko.co http://tester.net Just about anything else you'd like.

Output goal
$var[0] = http://marko.co
$var[1] = http://tester.net

First try:
    if ( $status =~ m/http:(\S)+/g ) {
        print "$&\n";
    }

Output:
http://marko.co

Second try:
    @statusurls = ($status =~ m/http:(\S)+/g);
    print "@statusurls\n";

Output:
o t

I'm new to regex, but since I'm using the same regex for each attempt, I don't understand why it's returning such different results.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

I've looked at these posts and either didn't find what I was looking for or didn't understand how to implement it:

This one seemed the most promising (and it's where I got the 2nd attempt from, but it didn't return the whole URL, just the letter:  [How can I store regex captures in an array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304577/how-can-i-store-regex-captures-in-an-array-in-perl)

This has some great stuff in it.  I'm curious if I need to look at the URL as a word since it's bookended by spaces:  [Regex Group in Perl: how to capture elements into array from regex group that matches unknown number of/multiple/variable occurrences from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459721/regex-group-in-perl-how-to-capture-elements-into-array-from-regex-group-that-mat)

This one offers similar suggestions as the first two.  [How can I store captures from a Perl regular expression into separate variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259784/how-can-i-store-captures-from-a-perl-regular-expression-into-separate-variables)

Solution:
    @statusurls = ($status =~ m/(http:\S+)/g);
    print "@statusurls\n";

Thanks!

Comment: Also - don't use `$&` - see the WARNING in the [perlre docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: `@urls = $status =~ m{ *(https*://[^ ]+) *}g;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to capture more than just one character. Try this regex instead:

```
m/http:(\S+)/g
```

Comment: Your answer was the push I needed in the right direction.  I used what you posted and moved the ( to the left of the http because I needed that in the result.  Thanks!