# Regex: get string between two characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract a string between the two characters `@` and `:` for the string:

```
test23@server:/var/
```

So, when I try to do something like,
`@([^.]*):`
or even 
`\@(\S+):`
I get `@server:`

I just want both `@` and `:` removed so I can get just the word `server`. Please help!

Comment: (1) With `*` quantifier in `[^.]*` you allow 'nothing' to match as well.  You don't say how you use that so I can't tell how it works out but it's probably wrong.  (Btw, in a straight-up match it works.)  (2) The `\S` is not-a-space, so it matches `:` as well. It will surely work if you limit it (make non-greedy) as `\@(\S+?):` (while it may work otherwise as well, if there are no more `:`)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes it did work. I mean making it non-greedy (\@(\S+?):) Thanks a lot!

Comment: PLease show your whole regex and how you use it

Comment: (Also, the `[^.]*` attempt should use `[^:]`, to exclude `:` and not `.`)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use a referrer to [capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259784/how-can-i-store-captures-from-a-perl-regular-expression-into-separate-variables) you just constructed or you can use `\K` token. You don't need to escape `@` character and `[^.]*` means greedily match everything except a literal dot `.` which is better to be changed to `[^:]+`:

```
@\K[^:]+
```

or more strictly:

```
@\K[^:]++(?=:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?<=@).*(?=:)`. I'm using positive lookbehind and positive lookahead.

It will match anything starting with (but excluding) `@` character and ending with (excluding) `:`

for detail, please see https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

see demo at https://regex101.com/r/jIIB9Q/1